# The use of "I wish"

Tags: grammaticality

If my co worker is always late to office meetings, is it correct to say:

> I wish he wouldn't be late to all the meetings

or

> I wish he wasn't late to all the meetings

Comment: They are almost identical, although the first version hints at the future, the last addresses the past.

Comment: There's also: " I wish he weren't late to all the meetings" which I rather prefer.

Comment: In the US, the second would more likely be *I wish he weren't* instead of *I wish he wasn't*.

Answer (score 0):

They're both OK, but they have slightly different nuances.

The first version uses a future tense, so it indicates a wish that the coworker would improve his behavior in the future, implying that he has been habitually late in the past.

The second version uses a past tense, so it's more of a complaint about his past behavior, while the hope that he'll improve is implied. As mentioned in the comments, it's considered more proper to use *weren't* rather than *wasn't*, but in casual use these are often interchanged.